# Internet not working, network card may be disabled

Tags: networking, internet

Hey so I have been using Linux for a few weeks now for school. I am at this part where I have to ping websites and paste screen shots of my terminal use. I have been struggling for the past couple weeks trying to get my internet to work while I am in Linux. I have tried a wired connection, and a wireless connection. My internet works fine when I am in Windows OS, but when I switch over to Linux it does not work. It says, "No network connections available." I tried creating a wired/wireless connection, it asked for information such as my: ssid, bssid, and mac address, I wasn't too sure on where to get a bssid but entered information to the best of my ability and it did not work. I had called my ISP trying to get help and they told me they couldn't help me. I even had a friend from Intel come over and try and help with no luck. I need this connection asap in order to complete my school work. I have searched dozens on forums looking for answers, I have entered quite a few commands into the terminal without luck. I have a suspicion that my network card may be disabled when I switch OS, if anyone could help with this I would appreciate it.
`

`lsb_release -d : Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
lspci -nn | grep 0280 : 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. device [168c:0034] (rev01)
rfkill list all : 0:hci0: bluetooth
                          soft blocked: no
                          hard blocked: no`

Comment: Please edit your question to add some details from these terminal commands: lsb_release -d and also: lspci -nn | grep 0280 and also: rfkill list all Thanks.